# Scraping ASP.NET site with Ruby

Tags: asp.net, ruby, screen-scraping

I would like to scrape the search results of this ASP.NET site using Ruby and preferably just using Hpricot (I cannot open an instance of Firefox): http://www.ngosinfo.gov.pk/SearchResults.aspx?name=&foa=0

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to go through each page of results. Basically, I need simulate clicking on links like these:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$2','')" class="blue_11" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Pager1">2</a>
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$3','')" class="blue_11" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Pager1">3</a>
```

etc.

I tried using Net::HTTP to handle the post, but while that received the correct HTML, there were no search results (I'm probably not doing that correctly). In addition, the URL of the page does not contain any parameters indicating page, so it is not possible to force the results that way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this, it worked for me. Quite the paradigm shift.
https://github.com/watir/watir-classic

Answer (score 8):

Using mechanize-1.0.0 the following works:

```
 agent = Mechanize.new
 page = agent.get('http://127.0.0.1/some.aspx')

 form = page.form("aspnetForm")
 form.add_field!('__EVENTARGUMENT', 'Page$2')
 form.add_field!('__EVENTTARGET', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvwSomeList')
 page = agent.submit(form) # this gets page 2
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just change the value for `__EVENTTARGET` and form and it will work.

Comment: When looping through a set of links within the same form, I use `form#add_field!` `form#submit` and then `form#delete_field!` with `__EVENTTARGET` (and any other necessary fields). This avoids adding multiple fields with the same name to your form as you iterate. Mechanize is a Godsend. In one recent case it picked up 174 form fields & their values - I just had to add the appropriate `__EVENTTARGET` field & value to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Even better check out Mechanize. A good starting point on screen scraping is the railscasts.com episode on mechanize.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mechanize does not handle Javascript links. I'm not familiar with ASP.NET at all, but is there a way to manually mimic what the Javascript is doing?

Comment: Sorry, I know almost nothing about asp.net. Maybe checking out what exactly `__doPostBack` does and getting the url would help? Also what platform are you on? You could always harness a full Webkit instance - though it seems way overkill for something this simple.

Comment: My app is currently running on a shared Unix server (hence my inability to start a Firefox instance). After clicking the link, the URL stays the same. There's a POST request made that is like "__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Pager1%242&__EVENTARGUMENT=" and then a __VIEWSTATE thing, but the value of too long to paste here. I've tried to read the documentation for this stuff, but have literally no ASP.NET experience, so it's not particularly clear to me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you're just getting started, you might want to check out [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).  It's more [lightweight and better-documented](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/175338) than Hpricot (which appears to have been abandoned).

Edit: Jakub Hampl is correct - [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) is what you're looking for to interact with web sites.  It works in cooperation with Nokogiri (which parses HTML and XML).